# how can I print the index of the first occurrence of some characters in another string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function made up of two strings:

```
def find_firstchars( chars, wholestring )
```

Which, when printed, returns the positions of each of those characters in the char string.  The first character in "chars" must mark the beginning of the index for the next character, so A is indexed first, then the function carries on indexing the next character after that position, and so on.

There may be multiple occurrences of the "chars" string in "wholestring", but I only need to index the characters of the first one.

For example,

```
print (find_firstchars( "ABC", "VMQOAJVBKRJCPGI" )
```

Would return the position list:
[4, 7, 11]

I've tried something like the code below, and beside the error I get in console for this about slice indices needing to be integers, I'm not sure how to efficiently search for each character in the following string.

```
def find_firstchars(chars, wholestring):
    index = 0 # Initializing index
    splice = [] # Initializing list
    while index != -1: # Run until at end of index
        index = chars.find(chars,wholestring) # Finds index value of each char in subsequence
        if index != -1: # If not at end:
            splice.append(index) # Append index value to splice list,
            index += 1 # Then keep looking
    return splice
print (find_firstchars("GTA", "ACGACATCACGTGACG"))
```

Though this should print [2, 6, 8].

Comment: How do you plan on handling cases where one of the letters of chars, is not found in wholestring? eg find_firstchars("GTX", "ACGACATCACGTGACG") 'X 'is not in wholestring

Comment: Good question, the scope of my assignment does not specify what result should be printed in this case, but perhaps nesting it in an if statement to print "Invalid char string" would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You are close:

```
def find_firstchars(chars, wholestring):
    index = 0 # Initializing index
    splice = [] # Initializing list
    for c in chars:
        index = wholestring.find(c,index)
        splice.append(index)
        index += 1 # Then keep looking
    return splice
print (find_firstchars("GTA", "ACGACATCACGTGACG"))
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the behavior of each character having to be found at a later index in the string than the prior character.  Look at the second example where the OP says that the result should be `[2, 6, 8]`.  With your code, you're going to get `[2, 6, 0]` instead. - I realize that the description at the beginning is unclear, but the example is unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, looking into this now. I should've also mentioned though that I need the first character in "chars" to mark the beginning of the index for the next character, so A is indexed first, then carry on indexing the next B after that position, and so on. That way, I get [2, 6, 8] in my 2nd test rather than [2, 6, 0]. Any ideas?

Edit: prior reply is correct.

Comment: Yes, you should have mentioned that.  I'll modify the answer.